# How to evaluate : $\int\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^{4}-1}}\text dt$

Tags: calculus

Is there any way to evaluate:  $$\int\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^{4}-1}}\text dt$$

I have started by using: $y=\sqrt{t^4-1}$

then:  $x=\sqrt{y^{2}+1}$

and finally: $x = \cosh(t)$

but I didn't get any result, any tips?

Comment: Did you consider using a halfway step of $x=t^2,\text dx = 2t\text dt$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have:
$$\int \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^4-1}}~dt$$
You can substitute $u=t^2$ and $du=2t~dt$ to obtain:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}~du$$
Which is a well known integral. If you want to derive the solution to this well known integral, consider using the substitution $u=\sec v$ and $du=\sec v\cdot \tan v~dv$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $t^2=\cosh x$ and the integral becomes $$\frac 12\int 1 dx=\frac 12\operatorname{arcosh}(t^2)+c$$

Comment: I can't vote twice, but +1 for skipping my "halfway step" altogether...

Comment: if $t^2=\cosh x$ then $dt =?$ I mean in general if you have : $g(t)=f(x)$ then how to evaluate $dt$ ?

Comment: $2tdt=\sinh xdx$ so you replace $tdt$ together...

Comment: ok thank you , so in general we have $g'(t)dt=f'(x)dx$ isn'it ?

Comment: Yes that's it..